# Django-constance: relation "constance_config" does not exist

Tags: python, django

I am having trouble using [`django-constance`](https://github.com/jazzband/django-constance).

I've followed the steps here: https://django-constance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html:

1. `pip install "django-constance[database]"`
2. add `'constance'` and `'constance.backends.database',` to `INSTALLED_APPS`
3. placed the following at the bottom of the settings file (it isn't callled `setings.py` but `common.py`):

   ```
   CONSTANCE_BACKEND = 'constance.backends.database.DatabaseBackend'
   CONSTANCE_DATABASE_PREFIX = 'constance:my_app_name:'
   CONSTANCE_CONFIG = {
       'THE_ANSWER': (42,
                      'Answer to the Ultimate Question of Life, The Universe, and Everything'),
   }
   ```
4. then ran `python manage.py migrate database`

But a table for dynamic settings wasn't created. This what happpens when I try to list `constance` settings:

```
$ python manage.py constance list
...
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "constance_config" does not exist
LINE 1: ...ce_config"."key", "constance_config"."value" FROM "constance...
```

I am running *Python 3.5.2*, *Django 1.11.3* and *django-constance 2.0.0*.

Any clue what is going on?

Comment: Try `python manage.py migrate` without `database`.

Comment: @AugustinLaville `No migrations to apply.` and the same result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not exactly sure why, but here's what worked:

1. the `database` initial migration was present

   ```
   $ python manage.py showmigrations database
   database
   [X] 0001_initial
   ```

   but the table itself was not

   ```
   \dt *constance*
   No matching relations found.
   ```
2. so I've removed that migration from `django_migrations`

   ```
   delete from django_migrations where app = 'database';
   ```
3. re-ran the migration

   ```
   python manage.py migrate database
   ```

and that's it. `constance list` behaves:

```
$ python manage.py constance list
THE_ANSWER  42
```

Answer (score 1):

Check `INSTALLED_APPS` on the your project settings file, if you want using database backend change similar below:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    # other apps
    'constance.backends.database',
)
```

[Read more](http://django-constance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends.html#database)